# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I am doing spring validation with hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final jar.When I add validation-api-1.1.0.Final jar file in my class path then this exception is occur:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.database.dao.UsersDAO com.layers.configuration.MyUsersDetailsService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userdao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.database.dao.UserDaoImplementation.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.layers.configuration.SpringConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My model class is :

```
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8605158460377236476L;
    private int UId;
    @Size(min=3, max=15)
    @NotNull
    private String userName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 15)
    private String userPassword;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=20)
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=20)
    private String lastName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UsersRoles> usersRoleNames;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(int UId) {
        this.UId = UId;
    }

    public Users(int UId, String userName, String userPassword, String firstName, String lastName,
            List<UsersRoles> usersRoleNames) {
        this.UId = UId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.usersRoleNames = usersRoleNames;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "u_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getUId() {
        return this.UId;
    }

    public void setUId(int UId) {
        this.UId = UId;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return this.userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usersTable")
    public List<UsersRoles> getUsersRoleNames() {
        return this.usersRoleNames;
    }

    public void setUsersRoleNames(List<UsersRoles> usersRoleNames) {
        this.usersRoleNames = usersRoleNames;
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String Save(/*@Valid Users user, BindingResult result,*/HttpServletRequest request, Model model, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean reverseBeforeSave) {

        if (result.hasErrors() || user.getUserName() == null || user.getUserPassword() == null
                || user.getUId() == 0 || user.getFirstName() == null || user.getLastName() == null) {
            return "error";
        }
        else
        {
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("last_name");
        System.out.println("save method");
        String[] roleNames = request.getParameterValues("roles");

        userService.saveUserandRoles(userName, password, firstName, lastName, roleNames);
        return "success";
        //}
    }
```

Please let me know what is the problem and how to fix it, I have read various tutorials and errors about this problem but not able to understand.

Comment: it seems there is version mismatch among the jars.

Comment: Can you share your full runtime classpath? What version of Tomcat is this?

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```